# Hadoop datanode -> namenode communication issue

Tags: hadoop

I have a Vagrant machine running a local Hadoop installation. Hadoop was working fine until today. Today Vagrant's insecure SSH key stopped working so I had to replace it. Now Hadoop is not working. In the logs I see:

`17/09/18 09:35:41 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: mymachine/192.168.33.10:8020. Already tried 0 time(s); maxRetries=45
17/09/18 09:36:01 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: mymachine/192.168.33.10:8020. Already tried 1 time(s); maxRetries=45
17/09/18 09:36:21 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: mymachine/192.168.33.10:8020. Already tried 2 time(s); maxRetries=45
17/09/18 09:36:41 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: mymachine/192.168.33.10:8020. Already tried 3 time(s); maxRetries=45`

The claim [here](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ServerNotAvailable) is that it's a datanode -> namenode communication issue. `core-site.xml` contains:

`<configuration>
      <property>
          <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
          <value>hdfs://mymachine:8020</value>
      </property>
  </configuration>`

Which is correct. Trying `getent hosts mymachine` yields `192.168.33.10`, which means the host is ok. I tried `sudo netstat -antp | grep 8020` and got:

`tcp        0      1 10.0.2.15:42002             192.168.33.10:8020          SYN_SENT    2630/java

tcp        0      1 10.0.2.15:42004             192.168.33.10:8020          SYN_SENT    2772/java

tcp        0      1 10.0.2.15:41998             192.168.33.10:8020          SYN_SENT    3312/java`

So it appears that the port is also ok. However, when I do `curl http://mymachine:8020` I get no reply. I checked on an identical machine and the correct reply should be `It looks like you are making an HTTP request to a Hadoop IPC port. This is not the correct port for the web interface on this daemon.`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are some answers in my opinion following:
1. Check if you can "ssh" to localhost without the password;
2. Check the authority when you start the hadoop;
3. It should be 127.0.0.1:8020 if running a local hadoop on your machine.Because the hadoop may run rightly while the network disconnecting...

Comment: As to 1 - the answer is yes. Can you explain how to do 2 & 3?

Comment: @Johnny , 2.Maybe you run the hadoop as a usual user but your hadoop is installed with a identify of root.  You don't have the authority to run hadoop. 3.Your hadoop is local model, So you can start the hadoop even if your machine is off the network. Local model only communicate with the "127.0.0.1",so the ip should be 127.0.0.1:8020 in my opinion.